# AWS EB Operational Error "Lost Connection to MySQL Server"

Tags: mysql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, operationalerror

I'm new to AWS services and I'm trying to deploy a simple Django app to Elastic Beanstalk. I found [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.RDS.html) that says "to decouple your database instance from your environment, you can run a database instance in Amazon RDS and configure your application to connect to it on launch."

I followed this documentation to set up a PostgreSQL DB and uploaded my source code. When I deployed the project, the health check passed. So I tried to follow the URL to my site, and it just tries to load forever.

I checked the error logs (/var/log/httpd/error_log) and found `OperationalError: (2013, "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0")`.

Why is it trying to connect to a MySQL when I want to use the PostgreSQL database?

Comment: MySQL and PostreSQL use different client software. Your application must be using the MySQL client to connect to RDS. Either use RDS MySQL or modify your application to use a PostreSQL client.

Comment: I tried modifying the application to use a PostreSQL client by changing the Database settings in the Configuration tab. The error message is gone but the web page still refuses to load.

Comment: Use a PostreSQL client program and verify that you can connect to the database.